# is HTTPS necessary for websites without forms?

Tags: security, https

Let's say I have a website without forms. It's just a static page with user interaction. Is SSL really necessary despite no data being sent back and forth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You indicated that your website does not have forms.

But does your website display any content that should be only seen by specific people?

If not -- then NO -- HTTPS is not necessary.

However, note that Google is giving a slight ranking precedence to HTTPS sites: http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2014/08/https-as-ranking-signal.html

Comment: Nope. Website just uses GIS mapping and image. That's it- really.

Comment: Then no, you do not *need* HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

[SSL/TLS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) offers not only encryption on your communication channel, but also identifies the server.

It you are afraid someone might put up a site and pretend to be you, SSL/TLS will give your users confidence they are connected to your site and not some imposter.